# How to programatically add vue directives to an element, i.e. v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js

We can programatically add custom attributes to an element like `element.attr('data-attr', someValue)` using plain JS, but what about Vue directives like a `v-if`

Given the following element

```
<p v-html="data.title"></p>
```

How can I add a v-if programatically? I am asking this for automation sake as there will be hundreds of dynamic variables that may or may not exist.

The desired outcome is

```
<p v-if="data.title" v-html="data.title"></p>
```

Only step I know is to grab the element in `created()` with a `ref`.

Comment: I am going to go on a whim and guess this is not possible, yet

Comment: Can you describe what you're meaning by 'there will be hundreds of dynamic variables' ? Does that mean that `<p v-if="data.title" v-html="data.title"></p>` must be generated in a `v-for` for example ?

Comment: This is the case for custom directive or component. You can manipulate props and elements in render function, and v-if becomes the regular if. Depends on your case how these elements need to be outputted, e.g. `p` or else.

Comment: If `data.title` is falsy - it will render as empty string. No real need for `v-if`. And if you want to get rid of margins/paddings on empty P tags - you can do this with CSS.

Comment: @Namysh great question, every one of the hundreds will have unique styles / elements, no looping :)

Comment: @IVOGELOV :o that is actually amazing, I didn't know :empty was possible!

Comment: @EstusFlask do you have a link as an example? Vue2 btw

Comment: The way to go is to use mixins here I guess (dirty tho).

Comment: @kissu sent you an email

Answer (score 0):

As per the statement - ***there will be hundreds of dynamic variables that may or may not exist.*** but if I see in one of your comment, You said ***no looping***. Then How you are rendering the dynamic elements ?

As per my understanding, You want to dynamically bind the data properties into HTML template. You can give a try to this solution to see if it works as per your requirement.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: {
        heading: '<H1>Heading 1</H1>',
      title: '<h3>Title 1</H3>'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-for="(item, index) in Object.keys(data)" :key="index"  v-html="data[item]"></p>
</div>
```

Above code snippet will always work for the dynamic properties that exists.

Comment: Good attempt Rohit, unfortunately the structure of the HTML will vary greatly so I cannot use for loops, i.e. the .title object will have some specific CSS / elements around it (i.e. divs). I cannot use for loops

Comment: @LeonA Then in that case, As anyhow you have to manually add the data properties for each element. You can also add `v-if` directive directly in the HTML template.